# Twitter followers count from the API is less than real count

Tags: php, twitter

I used Twitter API to get *followers* and *following* count. It's working fine, but there's one issue.

I take *followers* and *following* count as below.

```
$twitterData = $twitterConnection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" . $post['screen_name']);
$info = array();

if (!empty($twitterData)) {
    $info['followers'] = $twitterData->followers_count;
    $info['following'] = $twitterData->friends_count;
}
```

I got the count, but the count of followers i got from the API is less than what I see in real twitter page. Following count is same because it's a very small number and is not changing instantly, but followers count is a big number and changes its count in each minute.  I'm getting a difference of about 100 from real data.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Much of the data in Twitter and other large platforms is *eventually* consistent as well as being cached.